# Finding the limits in the enclosed volume between a paraboloid and parabolic cylinder.

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I've been struggling trying to work out the following exercise:

[image]

Here are some $xy$ and $yz$ cuts I've made when considering the limits of the following shape:

[image]
Here's a $xz$ picture of these two objects. I don't know if these two lines are actually creating an enclosed area - as, for instance, I don't know if the general line for $z=4\alpha ^2 + y^2$ even encloses the blue line, but I'm assuming it does since this would make the problem solvable (not a good justification, but..)
[image]

Here is the image of the two objects with constant $z$.

Here, I don't know if the general equation for the ellipse is actually even cut by the lines $y = \pm \sqrt{(4/3) - (\alpha/3)}$, so I don't know if the $y$ limit is the upper and lower ends of the ellipse or the equation of the two horizontal lines I specified in the previous sentence.

If these lines are for some constant $alpha$, how can I deduce the volume I'm sketching in? Depending on alpha, this can potentially change the limits, I'd think, as in the case of the second picture. With $alpha$ being sufficiently large, the ellipse is cut by the two lines.

Answer (score 2):

Equate equations $z=4x^2+y^2=4-3y^2$. We get, $x^2+y^2=1$.
Use cylindrical cordinate system.

$r:0\to 1$

$\theta:0\to 2\pi$

$z:4-3r^2\sin^2\theta \to r^2+3 \cos^2\theta$

$dxdydz=rdrd\theta dz$

Comment: I think that's wrong

Comment: Why do you say like that?

Comment: I wrote the correct limits below

Comment: I will soon edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Let me provide a solution without using cylindrical coordinates. 
Firstly you compute the intersection between the paraboloid and the parabolic cylinder which is given by 
$$x^2+y^2=1$$
Now you stop for a while and try to make sense of it visually. 
[image]

And now it should be clear that this is your desired integral. 
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\left(\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}^{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\left(\int_{4x^{2}+y^{2}}^{4-3y^{2}}dz\right)dy\right)dx$$

Just to make sure you understood, can you see why the above integral is equivalent to the one below? 
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\left(\int_{-\sqrt{1-y^{2}}}^{\sqrt{1-y^{2}}}\left(\int_{4x^{2}+y^{2}}^{4-3y^{2}}dz\right)dx\right)dy$$

Comment: Could you explain the justification of the $z$ limits I was confused about? I can see why they're equivalent, yes, as it's basically just swapping $x's$ for $y's$ and keeping everything the same, but I was wondering how the cylinder lines intersect with the ellipse and why we don't consider it in the limits.

Comment: I edited my answer... does it make more sense now? Is there smth still bothering you?

Comment: Given the diagram, there doesn't seem to be horizontal lines to even consider like the ones I drew in my second picture. I can see where you're coming from using the image -- just still not sure exactly *why* the lines of the cylinder I drew are wrong given my thought process, Like, I clearly see why the limits are the way they are here, I just don't have a good reason as to why my guess was *wrong*, if that makes sense.

Comment: It makes sense. In your second draw you're thinking what happens when you intersect the paraboloid and the parabolic cylinder with the plane $z=\alpha$ for $0<\alpha<4$ right? And indeed you don't know if there is an intersection... but if there isn't then the exercise doesn't really make sense like you argue. The key observation is: when you compute the intersection of both surfaces you get the limits for $x$ and $y$! Why? Because both surfaces behave "symmetrically", i.e. the paraboloid is getting wider as you go up the $z$ axis and the parabolic cylinder gets tighter as you go up. Better?

Answer (score 0):

Intersection : $4x^2+y^2=4-3y^2 \implies4y^2+4x^2=4 \implies x^2+y^2=1$

using Cylindrical coordinates:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x=rcos\theta\\
y=rsin\theta\\
z=z
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{4r^2cos^2\theta+r^2sin^2\theta}^{4-3r^2sin^2\theta}rdzdrd\theta=8\pi\int_{0}^{1}r-r^3dr=2\pi$